# zorder in matplotlib with shared x_axis doesn't put on top

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code, and the output figure:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()


color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Iterations')
ax1.set_ylabel('Non metric loss', color=color)
ax1.plot(net_loss_bigger, color=color, zorder=3)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('metric supervised loss', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(metric_super_loss_bigger, color=color, zorder=2)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
```

[image]

Ideas what I'm doing wrong? 
Without the shared `ax1.twinx()` it works as expected. workarounds?

Comment: zorder works within each axes. But of course you can set the zorder of the axes.

Comment: I've set it for each axis, and still the 'blue' is before the 'red'

Comment: The duplicate shows how to do it.

Comment: As the duplicate has a non-representable title, I think it's good the answer will be here too as well:)

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
ax1.set_zorder(ax2.get_zorder()+ax3.get_zorder()+1)
ax1.patch.set_visible(False)
```

[image]

does the desired functionallity